# An Upper Bound of $\left<H,X\right>_F$ with Constrainted Rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, eigenvalues

We have $X=[\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2...,\mathbf{x}_n]\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times n}$, $H=[\mathbf{h}_1,\mathbf{h}_2...,\mathbf{h}_n] \in\mathbb{R}^{d\times n}$, and $d<n$. $H$ has rank $r\leq d$ and $X$ has rank $d$.

Assume we have $\|H\|_F\leq C$ and $\|\mathbf{x}_i\|_2\leq R$, where $\|\cdot\|_F$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ are the Frobenius norm and vectro 2-norm respectively.

What do we know about the upper bound of Frobenius inner product $\left<H,X\right>_F$ of $H$ and $X$?

Hint:
I know by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $\left<H,X\right>_F < \sqrt nCR$. The equality will not hold because we can not guarantee $\mathbf{x}_i = k\mathbf{h}_i, \forall i$. This is because $H$ is rank deficient. I think there is a tighter upper bound for $<H,X>_F$ in terms of singular values of $X$ and rank $r$ of $H$.

I have also posted the question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330603/an-upper-bound-of-matrix-inner-product-lefth-x-right-f-with-constrainted-ra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the von Neuman trace inequality
$$
\langle H,X\rangle\equiv\mathrm{trace}(H^{T}X)\le\sum_{i=1}^{d}\sigma_{i}(H)\sigma_{i}(X)\equiv\langle\sigma(H),\sigma(X)\rangle
$$
where $\sigma_{i}(H)$ is the $i$-th largest singular value of $H$
and $\sigma(H)$ is the length-$d$ vector of singular values in decreasing
order. From here, you can apply the Hölder inequality
$$
\langle\sigma(H),\sigma(X)\rangle\le\|\sigma(H)\|_{1}\|\sigma(X)\|_{\infty}\equiv\sigma_{\max}(X)\;\sum_{i=1}^{d}\sigma_{i}(H).
$$
If $H$ is rank-deficient, then we expect the Nuclear norm $\sum_{i=1}^{d}\sigma_{i}(H)$
to be small, and the bound to be relatively tight.

Note that the von Neuman inequality is one of the identities on the wiki page for [trace inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_inequality). Also note that the nuclear norm is closely related to low-rank matrices. One can show that the nuclear norm is the convex envelope for the rank function over the Frobenius ball. See [Recht, Fazel, Parrilo (2010)](https://doi.org/10.1137/070697835).